# How to use a regular expression to extract a substring?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

so im trying to figure out regular expressions in Flex, but cant for the life of me figure out how to do the following.
From the sample below, i need to extract out only **"Mike_Mercury".**

So i have to somehow strip out everything around it with RegExp, or whatever's best. Also, I would need it to work with other samples as well. Im getting this from the `reddit api`, so id have to extract that same section from a whole bunch of these. Thanks!

```
 <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/atheism/comments/q2sfe/barack_obamas_insightful_words_on_abortion/">
                        <img src="http://d.thumbs.redditmedia.com/9StfiHi7hEbf8v73.jpg" alt="Barack Obama's insightful words on abortion"
                            title="Barack Obama's insightful words on abortion" /></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    submitted by <a href="http://www.reddit.com/user/Mike_Mercury">Mike_Mercury </a>
                    to <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/atheism/">atheism</a>
                    <br />
                    <a href="http://imgur.com/lKFYr">[link]</a> <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/atheism/comments/q2sfe/barack_obamas_insightful_words_on_abortion/">
                        [1722 comments]</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Use a HTML parser. Regex isn't going to parse arbitrary HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
submitted by <a href=".*?">(.*?)</a>
```